# Client threads can send only one message and stop

Tags: java, multithreading, client, client-server

I have two java classes one for that reads from the client threads and one that creates the client threads.. So, if i open n clients at the same time, the clients from 0 to n-1 can send only one message and then they can only receive while the n-th client can keep sending as much as he wants!

> here's the server code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;

/*
 * A chat server that delivers public and private messages.
 */
public class MultiThreadChatServerSync {

  // The server socket.
  private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  // The client socket.
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;


  // This chat server can accept up to maxClientsCount clients' connections.
  private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    // The default port number.
    int portNumber = 2222;
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatServerSync <portNumber>\n"
          + "Now using port number=" + portNumber);
    } else {
      portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
    }

    /*
     * Open a server socket on the portNumber (default 2222). Note that we can
     * not choose a port less than 1023 if we are not privileged users (root).
     */
    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    /*
     * Create a client socket for each connection and pass it to a new client
     * thread.
     */
    while (true) {
      try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == null) {
            (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
            break;
          }
        }
        if (i == maxClientsCount) {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
          os.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}

class clientThread extends Thread {
MultiThreadChatServerSync ms = new MultiThreadChatServerSync();
  private String clientName = null;
  //private DataInputStream is = null;
   private BufferedReader br = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final clientThread[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;

  public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
  }

  public void run() {
    MultiThreadChatServerSync mss = new MultiThreadChatServerSync();
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

    try {
      /*
       * Create input and output streams for this client.
       */
      //is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      String name;
      while (true) {
        System.out.println("Inside the while.. to send back the name");
        os.println("Enter your name.");
        System.out.println("Inside the while.. the name is sent");

        name = br.readLine().trim();
        if (name.indexOf('@') == -1) {
          break;
        } else {
          os.println("The name should not contain '@' character.");
        }
      }

      /* Welcome the new the client. */
      System.out.println(name  + " waas joined");
      os.println("Welcome " + name
          + " to our chat room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line.");
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
            threads[i].os.println("*** A new user " + name
                + " entered the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }
      }
      /* Start the conversation. */
      while (true) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("message: " + line);
        os.println("your message is received");
        if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
          break;
        }
        /* If the message is private sent it to the given client. */
        if (line.startsWith("@")) {
          String[] words = line.split("\\s", 2);
          if (words.length > 1 && words[1] != null) {
            words[1] = words[1].trim();
            if (!words[1].isEmpty()) {
              synchronized (this) {
              //  System.out.println("The message received is0: " + words[1]);
                for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                 // System.out.println("The message received is1: " + words[1]);
                  if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
                      && threads[i].clientName != null
                      && threads[i].clientName.equals(words[0])) {
                    threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    /*
                     * Echo this message to let the client know the private
                     * message was sent.
                     */
                   // System.out.println("The message received is2: " + words[1]);
                    this.os.println(">" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          /* The message is public, broadcast it to all other clients. */
          synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {

              if (threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null) {
                //System.out.println("Client name: " + threads[i].clientName);
                threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + line);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
              && threads[i].clientName != null) {
            threads[i].os.println("*** The user " + name
                + " is leaving the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }
      }
      os.println("*** Bye " + name + " ***");

      /*
       * Clean up. Set the current thread variable to null so that a new client
       * could be accepted by the server.
       */
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == this) {
            threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      /*
       * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
       */
      br.close();
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

> And this is the Client Code:

```
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiThreadChatClient implements Runnable {

  // The client socket
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  // The output stream
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  // The input stream
  //private static DataInputStream is = null;
  private static BufferedReader br;

  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      MultiThreadChatClient mc = new MultiThreadChatClient();
    // The default port.
    int portNumber = 2222;
    // The default host.
    String host = "localhost";

    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatClient <host> <portNumber>\n"
              + "Now using host=" + host + ", portNumber=" + portNumber);
    } else {
      host = args[0];
      portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
    }

    /*
     * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
     */
    try {
      clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
    //  System.out.println("The socket is opened..");
      inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      //is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
     //  System.out.println("The buffer reader is opened..");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
          + host);
    }

    /*
     * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data to the
     * socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber.
     */
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && br != null) {
      try {

        /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
      //  System.out.println("The thread is opening..");;
        new Thread(new MultiThreadChatClient()).start();
      //  System.out.println("The thread is opened..");

        while (!closed) {
         // Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         // String ss = s.nextLine();
          os.println(mc.inputLine.readLine().trim());
          //os.println(ss);
          // System.out.println("The message is sent");
        }
        /*
         * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
         */
        os.close();
        br.close();
        clientSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }

  /*
   * Create a thread to read from the server. (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
   */
  public void run() {
    /*
     * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the
     * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
     */
    //MultiThreadChatClient mcc = new MultiThreadChatClient();
    String responseLine;
    try {
      System.out.println("Insde the run..");
      //os.println(inputLine.readLine());
      while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("responseLine: " + responseLine);
        System.out.println(responseLine);
        if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1)
          break;
      }
      closed = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

I find this weird since the other clients can still receive the messages but can't send more than one!

Comment: why is `BufferedReader br` static (in class clientThread)?  This is likely your problem.  Each new thread needs a new instance of both input and output streams.

Comment: @IanMc I removed the static.. But now when i run i get the warning:

`Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MultiThreadChatClient.run(MultiThreadChatClient.java:101)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

And i can send messages to the server now from the clients to the server but the clients don't receive any response from the server!

Comment: Do you know which line this is: 101?

Comment: @IanMc `while ((responseLine = mcc.br.readLine()) != null) {`

I guess i'm not receiving any stream from the server now!

Comment: In the server, it is important to remove static reference.  It creates a Thread for each client connection.  However, the client is not the same case.  It may have static references if you want.  In the client, you have created a Thread which creates *another* instance of the client `MultiThreadChatClient mcc = new MultiThreadChatClient()`.  It is because of this, that 'br' is null in the client.  Why do you create a second instance of the client?

Comment: @IanMc well i only created it "as a debugging procedure" because before this second instance i had the same problem. So, i did it just to try..

Comment: OK.  Then in the client, I would use a static variable for br (and take away the debugging `new` line).  This way it will be visible to the line `while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null)`.  Does making it static fix the null ptr?

Comment: @IanMc i made it static again! and somehow the initial problem is solved also!! i don't understand how or why!!!!

Comment: Strange indeed.  Normally code isn't so lucky like that :) So you have no further problems?  And for curiosity you kept the `br` static in the server code?

Comment: @IanMc For now no more problems but i have more tasks to do.. no in the server i changed `br` to not static, maybe that is what solved the problem?!

Comment: Yes John, it is taking away static in the server which fixed it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As @John123 stated it probably is because you declare the Buffered Reader as static. When you do that there exists only one Buffered Reader across all MultiThreadChatClients. if you change one then you change all of them. The problem you are running into right now is because you don't declare mcc.br at any point. 
you can change this line

```
mc.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

to this

```
mcc.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

to fix that or add a declaration to mcc.br in a constructor.

I am only posting this as an answer because I don't have enough rep to comment. Also I would recommend changing the question back to include the buffered reader being static so that the question and answer makes sense.

Comment: The problem was because i declared `br` as static in the server. So, in both the client and the server `br` should not be static. And that fixed the problem.